# How to hide/remove a DIV when empty

Tags: jquery, css

I have some server side HTML output I cannot deal with using pure CSS, essentially the DIV sometimes holds:

```
<div><span>Content</span></div>
```

or

```
<div><p>Content</p></div>
```

or

```
<div>Content</div>
```

or

```
<div> </div>
```

When the DIV == `<div> </div>` I want to remove it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Even better (assuming jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('div:empty').remove(); });
```

EDIT: The other answers are good, but the OP wanted to remove the empty item, not hide it.

Answer (score 66):

You can do this using only CSS:

```
div:empty { display: none }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer doing a minimum to succeed. Don't fire up jQuery if CSS alone is sufficient.

Comment: Best solution, but it does not work in IE8 and older versions of IE http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: hide and remove are not the same, remove completely takes it out of the DOM, hence, it can not even be validated

Comment: Late to the party here, but this would actually fail for the example (`<div> </div>`) - `:empty` only works if there is nothing between the opening and closing tags, i.e., `<div></div>`

Answer (score 10):

I think you can do the following:

```
$(function() {
  $("div:empty").hide();
});
```

jQuery's [empty](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/empty) pseudo selector is great.

Comment: That's pretty cool, I didn't know about the empty pseudo selector

Answer (score 7):

Here's another easy way...
using the filter()...

```
$('div').filter(function() {

  return $.trim($(this).text()) === ''

}).remove()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use CSS-only to solve this, putting a table with `style="empty-cells:hide"` around the content, and changing the `div` to a `td`, like this:

Before:

`<div>Content</div>`

After:

`<table style="empty-cells:hide"><tr><td>Content</td></tr></table>`

Comment: [`empty-cells`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/empty-cells) beats [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) by one version of IE (8.0 vs 9.0).  Still somewhat useful (even 3-4 years after this answer was posted) but given the amount of extra structure added and the amount of time that's passed since IE 8, future readers may want to stick with `:empty` backed up by a Javascript solution.