# How to hide empty sections in a WebContent portlet

Tags: liferay, portlet

We are creating a site in 3 languages. We have some Web content display in boxes, use "Look and feel/Advanced Styling" to provide a border. The portlet title is defined in the look and feel of the portlet.

When there is no text in one language, we would like the boxes to be not displayed.

Can someone help us ?

Thanks in advance,

s

Comment: let me know if my edit makes sense - it was hard to know what you wanted to ask, this is what I understood (and answered). Otherwise edit again and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455112) is very close to what you're looking for (unless you want to hide the element server side).

[Translated to AUI](http://deploy.alloyui.com/docs/) (as it's available in Liferay rather than jQuery) the answer is similar to this (containing simple demo code):

```
 <div style="border:5px solid blue"></div>
 <div style="border:1px solid red">
    This is not empty
 </div>
 <script>
   AUI().use(function(A){
     A.all("div:empty").hide();
   });
 </script>
```

A more elegant, server side option is to create a structure and a template and do the conditional logic (e.g. HTML generation) with Velocity, so that empty content doesn't even generate the markup (not shown, as I don't know which option you prefer, and one solution is already there)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide whole WebContent-Portlet when this article hasn't contet with a language of current user, then you can override the `html/portlet/journal_content/view.jsp` with Liferay-Hook. You can find the tutorial for jsp overriding on liferay documentation: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/overriding-a-j-4

ps: to proofe existing of language by the JournalArticle you can use LanguageUtil class.