# How can I remove element's height when its value is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML structure like this:

```css
li{
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    padding:4px;
}

div{
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 6px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>something</span>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>something</span>
    <div>something else</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And this is expected result:

[image]

I guess I can do that by JS, something like this:

```
if ( $('div').val() == '' ) {
    $('div').hide();
}
```

But I want to know can I do that by pure HTML and CSS ?

Comment: Well why my question has earned one vote to be close as *unclear* ? Really is it unclear? I've provided a screenshot of the expected result... still it is unclear ?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide/remove a DIV when empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455112/how-to-hide-remove-a-div-when-empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need old browser support, you could just use line height for spacing instead.

```css
 li{
      list-style: none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid;
      padding:4px;
    }
    
    div{
      background-color: #eee;
      // padding: 6px 0;
      line-height: 2;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>something</span>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>something</span>
    <div>something else</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not sure it would work, but if it works, then that's a great idea .. upvote anyway

Answer (score 10):

You can use the :empty pseudo selector:

```
 div:empty {
    display: none;
 }
```

```css
li{
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    padding:4px;
}

div{
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 6px 0;
}

div:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>something</span>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>something</span>
    <div>something else</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: great .. upvote .. but sadly the most of my website's users use old browsers like IE7 `:-(` .. So I cannot use this approach.

Comment: Encourage your users to use modern browsers.

Comment: @stack You can add an alert bar at the top of the page, many sites do this. you may implement this through https://browser-update.org/ for example or create a basic alert with IE conditional tags

Answer (score 1):

use :empty | CSS-Trick

```
 div:empty{
       display:none;
      }
```

[reference from :empty | css-Trick](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery like

```
$('div:empty').hide();
```

Comment: It was specified in the question that the solution should be HTML and CSS based.