# Hiding Div when Empty through CSS when using a certain style

Tags: html, css

I want to hide `div` when it is empty, through CSS, preferably, but I already applied a style that I don't want to sacrifice.

Here is my code rendered as:

```
<div class="auto-style2"></div>
```

Here is my second style:

```
.auto-style2 {
    width: 1100px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
```

I tried: `empty-cells: hide;`, but that didn't work.

The link below recommended, `div:empty { display: none }`;

But since my div is already using a different style, I would think that it would have to be done through that style only; I think it is going to ignore `div:empty`; because the second is applied to my div.

Related:
[How to hide/remove a DIV when empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455112/how-to-hide-remove-a-div-when-empty)

Comment: Do you expect C# in the answer? if not there is no need to use the tag

Comment: i am coding in c#...but it is generating all this other html i am working with....i thought c# coders will be good audience to answer....  should i remove c#?

Comment: `.auto-style2:empty { display: none; }`

Comment: ^ His rendered code is not empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
`.auto-style2:empty { display: none }`
```

This will work along with your existing `.auto-style2{...}`.

Note: For empty to work, it has to be literally empty. If there any visible white spaces it wont work.

```css
.auto-style1 {
    width: 1100px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.auto-style1:empty{
  display:none;
}

.auto-style2 {
    width: 1100px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.auto-style2:empty{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
.auto-style1 shows up cause of white spaces.
<div class="auto-style1"> </div>

.auto-style2 is hidden below this line.
<div class="auto-style2"></div>
```

Comment: while there were no syntactical complaints, it didn't work.  I am still seeing a big blank box on screen with scroll bar on the right side...  I am trying to figure out how to get rid of that, because it is rendered as empty div (only with style 2 applied).

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there are no insvisible chars in the div ?

Comment: in my second example .auto-style2, notice there are no blank spaces inside the div.
like so, *<div class="auto-style2"></div>*

Comment: NOTE:  as mentioned by answer-er, in order to get this to work, I had to remove all spaces... If there is a single blank space within div tag, it will fail.

Comment: @HillOfBeans Yes, `:empty` works only for really empty divs. There's a CSS working-draft for `:blank` which would select all empty divs, even if they have whitespace in it. But it's not supported by any browser yet, so it can take a while until it's usable-

Answer (score 0):

You can give the div an #ID and then do:

```
ID:empty{display: None}
```